# Tor browser GUI displaying codes instead of characters

Tags: user-interface, browser, tor

I cannot change **Tor's GUI** to English or anything I understand (Western-EU or even cyrillic) because it looks like on the image. I did uninstall it and removed the /etc/tor directory, then I installed it again just to find the same problem.

[image: Tor... well, look at the picture to understand the problem]

Answer (score 0):

System: Fedora 35

I solved it by **removing the RPM package** using the software applet, then selected **Flathub as the software source** to get a Flatpak package and installed that.

The GUI is now human friendly :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Fedora 34 and got the same problem after tor update to 11.0.1. I installed Tor Browser Launcher from flathub. Launcher downloaded its own tor browser instance and it works.